No load_controller and unload_controller services available in controller_manager node
I am having an issue with my ROS package for my robot "sja”
https://github.com/MateS90s/sja_test1.git
I cant run the robot in gazebo because the controller_manager node seems to be missing the load_controller and unload_controller services. The launch process finishes with an error:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/mat/.ros/log/2024-06-12-12-02-09-149104-mat-5500
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [5504]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [5506]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [5508]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [5510]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-5]: process started with pid [5512]
[INFO] [rosbridge_websocket-6]: process started with pid [5514]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-7]: process started with pid [5516]
[static_transform_publisher-7] [WARN] [1718186529.699236371] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718186529.766052641] [static_transform_publisher_bTHtEJSuLQtsx4s6]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-7] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-7] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-7] from 'map' to 'base_link'
[robot_state_publisher-3] [WARN] [1718186529.770178492] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718186529.771059697] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718186529.771128175] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1718186529.771132831] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[joint_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1718186530.111261111] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[rosbridge_websocket-6] [INFO] [1718186530.251959208] [rosbridge_websocket]: Rosbridge WebSocket server started on port 9090
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186530.256050466] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186530.256251211] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186530.257834299] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186530.277114476] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186530.277329968] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186531.056239387] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1718186531.286286638] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [sja]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5510]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-8]: process started with pid [5812]
[ros2_control_node-8] [INFO] [1718186539.884538423] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-8] [INFO] [1718186539.886380561] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-8] [INFO] [1718186539.893092699] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[INFO] [spawner-9]: process started with pid [6027]
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1718186557.956323559] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[INFO] [spawner-10]: process started with pid [6103]
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1718186559.976926019] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1718186561.996842006] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1718186562.652658105] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1718186564.014099880] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1718186564.668089147] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-9] [ERROR] [1718186566.033948941] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-9]: process has died [pid 6027, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_controller --ros-args'].
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1718186566.682511417] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-10] [INFO] [1718186568.702006103] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-10] [ERROR] [1718186570.723376699] [spawner_arm_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-10]: process has died [pid 6103, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner arm_controller --ros-args'].

When I use the command ros2 service list to list available services. The controller_manager node appears with several services, but the load_controller and unload_controller services are not listed.
:~$ ros2 service list
/apply_joint_effort
/apply_link_wrench
/clear_joint_efforts
/clear_link_wrenches
/controller_manager/describe_parameters
/controller_manager/get_parameter_types
/controller_manager/get_parameters
/controller_manager/list_parameters
/controller_manager/set_parameters
/controller_manager/set_parameters_atomically
/delete_entity
/gazebo/describe_parameters
/gazebo/get_parameter_types
/gazebo/get_parameters
/gazebo/list_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters_atomically
/get_model_list
/joint_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/joint_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/joint_state_publisher/get_parameters
/joint_state_publisher/list_parameters
/joint_state_publisher/set_parameters
/joint_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
/pause_physics
/reset_simulation
/reset_world
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
/rosbridge_websocket/describe_parameters
/rosbridge_websocket/get_parameter_types
/rosbridge_websocket/get_parameters
/rosbridge_websocket/list_parameters
/rosbridge_websocket/set_parameters
/rosbridge_websocket/set_parameters_atomically
/spawn_entity
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/describe_parameters
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/get_parameter_types
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/get_parameters
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/list_parameters
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/set_parameters
/static_transform_publisher_RNwmyhBwf5pWWMJp/set_parameters_atomically
/unpause_physics

I’m using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu is installed on virtual machine (Oracle VM) on Widows 10
Thank you in advance for your help.
